# How to increase MySQL INSERT performances?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a program to collect infomation from many merchants.

Each request from merchant, my program do an InSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO `good` (id,code,merchant,netcost,ip) values('','GC8958','merchantname','581000','192.168.34.30');
```

There are many request from merchants at a time ( over 500+ request ) so MYSQL do 500+ insert query.

Is this a problem and how can I solve it with MYSQL?

Comment: what you mean to increase mysql engine?

Comment: Your program could buffer those requests and insert them in intervals of 10 or something like that.

Comment: MySQL batches is the answer

Comment: @machineaddict: I think my program can not use MySql batches because INSERT query come from requests of merchants.

Comment: @SaviorNguyen: That's exactly what MySQL batches do. Collect data to create a query with lower length then maximum query size allowed and insert it into database. Then go to batch number 2...

Comment: If it makes sense to do so, remove all indexes from the table. Obviously, this comes at a cost when retrieving data! Also, MyISAM may perform better but again, at a cost.

Comment: Using prepared statements should improve the performances [Manual prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (with php)

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem unless you're strapped for hardware (in which case the answer is "faster disk, more RAM, faster CPU" **once you verify which of the three is the bottleneck on average**). You can "paper over" peaks using the [`INSERT DELAYED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-delayed.html) syntax if you use MyISAM tables (it's likely not worth it; the syntax has been deprecated).

If you're doing this in batches (i.e. not different clients each inserting one row) then multiple `INSERT`s or even `LOAD DATA INFILE` will be a huge help. In a pinch, you can save them unindexed on disk, or session (which amounts to the same thing)... (or maybe in a small `MEMORY` table - but I'd run some tests before resorting to that) and run the real `INSERT` at leisure.

I'd leave further optimizations for later; "*premature optimization is the root of all evil*". Anyhow, you may be interested in [some](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2616674/database-administration/10-essential-performance-tips-for-mysql.html) [Google](http://seravo.fi/2013/improve-mysql-performance-to-speed-up-websites) [results](http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/23/improve-innodb-performance-write-bound-loads/) (this last deals with esoterics such as "*the question is: is it better to have the InnoDB double write buffer enabled or to use the ext4 transaction log*").

Comment: *Love of * premature optimisation is the root of all evil